# Pandas turn last N columns into NA based on another dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following dataframes:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data={'col1': ['a', 'd', 'g', 'j'], 
                        'col2': ['b', 'c', 'i', np.nan], 
                        'col3': ['c', 'f', 'i', np.nan],
                        'col4': ['x', np.nan, np.nan, np.nan]},
                index=pd.Series(['ind1', 'ind2', 'ind3', 'ind4'], name='index'))
```

| index | col1 | col2 | col3 | col4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ind1 | a | b | c | x |
| ind2 | d | c | f | NaN |
| ind3 | g | i | i | NaN |
| ind4 | j | NaN | NaN | NaN |

```
df2 = pd.Series(data=[True, False, True, False],
                index=pd.Series(['ind1', 'ind2', 'ind3', 'ind4']))
```

|  |  |
| --- | --- |
| ind1 | True |
| ind2 | False |
| ind3 | True |
| ind4 | False |

How do I make the last 2 values for each row in `df1` into NA, based on the boolean values of `df2`?

In this case, since `ind1` and `ind3` are True, it would impact the same indices in `df1`.

| index | col1 | col2 | col3 | col4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ind1 | a | b | NaN | NaN |
| ind2 | d | c | f | NaN |
| ind3 | g | i | NaN | NaN |
| ind4 | j | NaN | NaN | NaN |

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A possible solution, based on [`pandas.DataFrame.mask`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.mask.html):

```
df1[['col3', 'col4']] = df1[['col3', 'col4']].mask(df2)
```

Output:

```
      col1 col2 col3 col4
index                    
ind1     a    b  NaN  NaN
ind2     d    c    f  NaN
ind3     g    i  NaN  NaN
ind4     j  NaN  NaN  NaN
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [boolean indexing](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
N = 2
df1.iloc[df2, -N:] = np.nan
```

*NB. what you call `df2` is actually a Series, `s`/`ser` might be more appropriate as a name.*

output:

```
      col1 col2 col3 col4
index                    
ind1     a    b  NaN  NaN
ind2     d    c    f  NaN
ind3     g    i  NaN  NaN
ind4     j  NaN  NaN  NaN
```